# Почему не попадает название в name?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть модель `form.php`:

```
public $date;
public static function checkFormData()
{
  $allNameEx = exercise::getAllExercises();

  foreach($allNameEx as $item)
  {
    $nameEx[] = $item['name'];
  }

  return $nameEx;
}
```

Переменная `$nameEx` возвращает:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sport
    [1] => Reading
    [2] => Paint
    [3] => Walk
)
```

В views/index я создаю форму:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),['dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'])?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->checkboxList(form::checkFormData()); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

У меня создается форма с чекбоксами и названиями чекбоксов:

```
<div id="form-name">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="form[name][]" value="0"> Sport</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="form[name][]" value="1"> Reading</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="form[name][]" value="2"> Paint</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="form[name][]" value="3"> Walk</label>
</div>
```

**В `label` названия с массива тянутся, а вот в `name="form[name][]"` они не попадают, почему?**

**И как мне в контроллере получить доступ к проверке поставлена ли галочка на чекбоксе или нет?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема была в том, что у меня не было занесено в rules мое название chechboxlist'a, то есть 'name'